# what happens when name node fails, which process will monitor name node heart beat status?

Tags: hadoop

Name node will have all the data nodes information, Name node interacts with all data nodes for its active state, if any data node does down, name node will start using the same task with other data nodes. My question here is what if name node it self fails? who will watch name node active state (Heart Beat) ?

Answer (score 4):

Prior to Hadoop 2.0.0, the NameNode was a single point of failure (SPOF) in an HDFS cluster. Each cluster had a single NameNode, and if that machine or process became unavailable, the cluster as a whole would be unavailable until the NameNode was either restarted or brought up on a separate machine.

There is no automatic recovery or no system to monitor the name node failure.

However, in the hadoop 2.0, we have new feature called HDFS High availability. Where we can configure active name node and standby name node.

Have a look at the below diagram.

[image]

Comment: Here is a [blog](http://www.cloudera.com/blog/2012/03/high-availability-for-the-hadoop-distributed-file-system-hdfs/) from Cloudera on the same.