# Hadoop Cluster Failover

Tags: hadoop

I have some questions about the Hadoop Cluster datanode failover:

```
1: What happen the link is down between the namenode and a datanode 
   (or between 2 datanodes) when the hadoop cluster is processing some data?
   Does Hadoop cluster have any OOTB to recover this problem?
2: What happen one datanode is down when the hadoop cluster is processing 
   some data?
```

Also, another question is about the hadoop cluster hardware configuration. Let's say we will use our hadoop cluster to process 100GB log files each day, how many datanodes do we need to set up? And for each datanode hardware configuration(e.g. CPU, RAM, Hardisk)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**1: What happen the link is down between the namenode and a datanode 
   (or between 2 datanodes) when the hadoop cluster is processing some data?
   Does Hadoop cluster have any OOTB to recover this problem?**

NN will not receive any heartbeat from that node and hence consider it as dead. In such a case the task running on that node will be scheduled on some other node having that data.

**2: What happen one datanode is down when the hadoop cluster is processing 
   some data?**

Same as above.

For the second part of your question :

It totally depends on your data and the kind of processing you are going to perform and a few other things. 100G is not a suitable candidate for MR processing on the first place. But, if you still need it any decent machine would be sufficient enough to process 100G data.

As a thumb rule you can consider :

- **RAM :** 1G RAM for each 1 million HDFS blocks+some additional for other things.
- **CPU :** Based totally on your needs.
- **Disk :** 3 times your datasize(if replication factor =3)+some additional space for stuff like temporary files, other apps etc. JBOD is preferable.

Frankly speaking the process is a lot more involved. I would strongly suggest you to go through **[this](http://blog.cloudera.com/blog/2013/08/how-to-select-the-right-hardware-for-your-new-hadoop-cluster/)** link in order to get a proper idea.

I would start with a cluster with 5 machines :

1. **1 * Master(NN+JT)** -

   **Disk :** 3 * 1TB hard disks in a JBOD configuration (1 for the OS, 2 for the FS image)

   **CPU :** 2 quad core CPUs, running at least 2-2.5GHz

   **RAM :** 32 GB of RAM
2. **3 * Slaves(DN+TT) -**

   **Disk :** 3 * 2 TB hard disks in a JBOD (Just a Bunch Of Disks) configuration

   **CPU :** 2 quad core CPUs, running at least 2-2.5GHz

   **RAM :** 16 GB of RAM
3. **1 * SNN -**

   I would keep it same as master machine.

Comment: Tariq: If I want to do some very complicate/crazy queries for our output which hadoop MapReduce generates, which better do you think for Pig and HBase?

Comment: Both are totally different. HBase is just a datastore. while Pig is a data processing tool.

Comment: As far as I known, if I build the HBase on top of HDFS, actually all data will be stored into HDFS, so HBase just like a interface, right?

Comment: Although HBase runs on top of your HDFS, both have very different nature. HBase is used when you need real-time random read/write access to a part of your data, while HDFS is a better fit if you need to batch process your entire dataset. So, it basically depends on what exactly is your requirement.

Comment: Oh one question, why the hardware configuration for master node is higher than the datanode? The masternode should be the light weighted one, right?

Comment: Since you are not going to do a lot of processing your slaves will be sitting idle most of the time. I don't find any sense in spending unnecessarily. Also, master should not be light weighted. It has got high memory consumption. It holds all the metadata in-memory. So, as your data grows, the memory consumption shoots up significantly.

Answer (score 1):

1. Depending on whether the namenode or datanode is down, the [job will be rewired to different](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15642688/what-happens-when-name-node-fails-which-process-will-monitor-name-node-heart-be) machines. HDFS was specifically designed for this. Yes, it's definitely out of the box.
2. If there are more datanodes available then the job is transferred.

100GB is [not large enough](http://www.linkedin.com/groups/What-is-realistic-minimum-size-988957.S.175321247) to justify using hadoop. [Don't use hadoop unless you absolutely need to.](http://www.chrisstucchio.com/blog/2013/hadoop_hatred.html)

Comment: Q1: If the name node and datanode are still alive but the Internet transaction is down, the job will be rewired to another datanode?

Comment: pick a another datanode to do this job again automatically?

Comment: If I really need to use Hadoop, could you give me some hardware  configuration recommendation, if I have 3 datanodes?